# jquery: how to update keyup event for accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion, keyup

I have a search functionality, which shows only particular panels of an accordion, when a search query is matched. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsXGp/). The accordion is expanded (class="in"), when sth is matched. Once the search field is cleared, I would like the accordion to go back to collapsed. For that, I try to remove the added class="in", but it seems it is not refreshed, when the field is cleared. Any ideas?

```
    var $infoPanels = $('.panel-info'),
    cachedText = [];
$infoPanels.each(function (i, v) {
    cachedText[i] = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
});

$('#search-criteria').on('keyup', function () {
    var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (g !== ""){
    $infoPanels.parentsUntil('.accordion').hide().removeClass("in");
    }
    $.each(cachedText, function (i, v) {
        if (g.length > 0 && v.indexOf(g) !== -1) {
            $infoPanels.eq(i).show().parentsUntil('.accordion').addClass("in").show();
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE:
I got this working by adding an else if, see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Y87R/).

Answer (score 0):

The code checks if the `search-criteria` has a value and then removes the class.  Instead it should check if `g == ""`, then remove the class.  Also add an `else` clause to that condition so the `in` class is not added when `g == ""`.

```
$('#search-criteria').on('keyup', function () {
    var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    if (g == ""){  //check if g is empty string

        $infoPanels.parentsUntil('.accordion').hide().removeClass("in");

    }else{ //if not empty add the class

        $.each(cachedText, function (i, v) {
            if (g.length > 0 && v.indexOf(g) !== -1) {
               $infoPanels.eq(i).show().parentsUntil('.accordion').addClass("in").show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/bsXGp/2/

Comment: Thank you for your help, Kevin. When the search field is cleared, everything is gone in your solution. It should only remove the class not hide the accordion. But I used your idea to add an else if ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Y87R/). This works in my home version fine if I delete the chars very slowly, otherwise only the accordions that matched the search term are displayed.

Comment: @Blitz Glad I could help! Admittedly I was a little unsure of the requirements.  Good job figuring it out.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot vote this up yet with a reputation below 15. Will do later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $infoPanels = $('.panel-info'),
    cachedText = [];
$infoPanels.each(function (i, v) {
    cachedText[i] = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
});

$('#search-criteria').on('keyup', function () {
    var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $infoPanels.hide();
    $.each(cachedText, function (i, v) {
        if (g.length > 0 && v.indexOf(g) !== -1) {
            $infoPanels.eq(i).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6epUv/) or [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6epUv/2/)

Comment: Thank you. This solution will hide only the content of the panels, but all accordions are shown with and without a search. I want only the relevant accordion and info-panel siblings to be shown.